# How to use OCR to read characters engraved on a metallic plate if both the background and the foreground are of the same color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

[**Character engraved on a metal plate**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYxg7.png)

How to extract the characters engraved on a metallic plate?
OCR( Pytesseract) is unable to give good results. I tried Ridge detection but in vain. Any form of threshold doesn't seem to work because the background and the foreground are of the same color. Is there a series of steps that I can follow for such a use-case?

Comment: Hey Satwik, maybe this could help you https://abbyy.technology/en:features:ocr:cameraocr-preprocessing-binarisation
Just look for OCR Image Preprocessing or binarisation. Give it a shot!

Comment: Hi JanMer, thank you for your suggestion.  Could you suggest me an alternate solution because I can't use ABBYY since it's paid?

Comment: Have you found any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I think Binarization wont work in your image. If any preprocessing improves the quality of this image that doesn't mean that same method will work on all the images you have.

So my suggestion is to create your own Custom OCR using machine learning or CNN.
You can convert your digits into a 28x28 image matrix and then reshape it into 1x784 matrix and perform the training like MNIST dataset is trained.

Comment: Astrick, thank you for your suggestion. I'll try doing that.